# Only show plotted points x-axis labels in line chartjs

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I want the following chart to show the x-axis labels for the 3 specified plotted points (365 Days, 730 Days, and 1095 Days) and hide the rest of the labels for the x-axis but the labels should still show up when you hover over the line as tooltips.

[image]

I tried multiple solutions including this callback method but it doesn't work as expected:

```js
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      userCallback: function(value, index) {
        if (index === 364 || index === 729 || index === 1094)
          return this.getLabelForValue(value);
        else
          return null;
      },
      autoSkip: false
    }
  }],
```

By the way, here's my full code for the line chart, maybe it have to do something with the x-axis labels that I get from an array:

```js
// Reward Over Time Chart Function
var rewardChart = null;
var ctx3 = document.getElementById('rewardOverTimeChart').getContext('2d');

rewardChartCreator(13);

function rewardChartCreator(dailyRewardUSD) {
  // Set time period
  const days3Years = 365 * 3;

  // Calculate the rewards over time
  var rewards = [];
  for (let day = 1; day <= days3Years; day++) {
    rewards.push(dailyRewardUSD * day);
  }

  if (rewardChart != null) {
    rewardChart.destroy(); // DESTROYING OLD CHART BEFORE CREATING NEW ONE
  }

  // Create the chart
  rewardChart = new Chart(ctx3, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: Array.from({ length: days3Years }, (_, i) => i === 0 ? '1 Day' : `${i + 1} Days`),
      datasets: [{
        label: ' Reward',
        data: rewards,
        borderColor: '#00ABE7', // Blue
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(254, 33, 209, 0.2)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        pointBackgroundColor: rewards.map((_, i) => [364, 729, 1094].includes(i) ? 'white' : '#00ABE7'),
        pointRadius: function(context) {
          let index = context.dataIndex;
          return [364, 729, 1094].includes(index) ? 10 : 1;
        },
        pointHoverRadius: 4,
        fill: true
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            userCallback: function(value, index) {
              if (index === 364 || index === 729 || index === 1094)
                return this.getLabelForValue(value);
              else
                return null;
            },
            autoSkip: false
          }
        }],
        x: {
          display: false,
          type: 'category',
          position: 'bottom',
        },
        y: {
          title: {
            display: false,
            text: 'Reward',
            font: {
              size: 16,
              weight: 'bold'
            }
          },
          ticks: {
            stepSize: 300,
            callback: function(value) {
              if (value == 0)
                return '$' + 100;
              else
                return '$' + value;
            }
          }
        }
      },
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
        tooltip: {
          callbacks: {
            label: function(context) {
              let label = context.dataset.label || '';
              if (label) {
                label += ': ';
              }
              if (context.parsed.y !== null) {
                label += new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                  style: 'currency',
                  currency: 'USD'
                }).format(context.parsed.y);
              }
              return label;
            }
          }
        }
      },
      animation: {
        duration: 1000, // Animation duration in milliseconds
        easing: 'easeInOutElastic' // Easing function for the animation
      },
      elements: {
        point: {
          radius: customRadius,
          display: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

function customRadius(context) {
  let index = context.dataIndex;
  let value = context.dataset.data[index];
  return index = 364 || index == 729 || index == 1094 ? 10 : 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="rewardOverTimeChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: The [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.0.2/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats) for v3.0 say that the name of the callback is `callback`, there's no `userCallback`.

Comment: Thanks, tried `callback` as well but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it by removing xAxes and adding `autoSkip: false` and the following `callback` function to the x-axis ticks.

- Renamed `options.scales.xAxes` (array) to `options.scales.x` (object)
- Added `options.scales.x.grid.display=false`
- Added `options.scales.x.display=true`
- Added `options.scales.x.type='category'`
- Added `options.scales.x.position='bottom'`
- Added `options.scales.ticks.autoSkip=false`
- Moved `options.scales.ticks.userCallback` to `options.scales.ticks.callback`
- Changed callback to return `''` instead of `null` in the `else` block

Here's the complete functional code:

```js
// Reward Over Time Chart Function
var rewardChart = null;
var ctx3 = document.getElementById('rewardOverTimeChart').getContext('2d');

rewardChartCreator(13);

function rewardChartCreator(dailyRewardUSD) {
  // Set time period
  const days3Years = 365 * 3;

  // Calculate the rewards over time
  var rewards = [];
  for (let day = 1; day <= days3Years; day++) {
    rewards.push(dailyRewardUSD * day);
  }

  if (rewardChart != null) {
    rewardChart.destroy(); // DESTROYING OLD CHART BEFORE CREATING NEW ONE
  }

  // Create the chart
  rewardChart = new Chart(ctx3, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: Array.from({ length: days3Years }, (_, i) => i === 0 ? '1 Day' : `${i + 1} Days`),
      datasets: [{
        label: ' Reward',
        data: rewards,
        borderColor: '#00ABE7', // Blue
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(254, 33, 209, 0.2)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        pointBackgroundColor: rewards.map((_, i) => [364, 729, 1094].includes(i) ? 'white' : '#00ABE7'),
        pointRadius: function(context) {
          let index = context.dataIndex;
          return [364, 729, 1094].includes(index) ? 10 : 1;
        },
        pointHoverRadius: 4,
        fill: true
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      scales: {
        x: {
          grid: {
            display: false
          },
          display: true,
          type: 'category',
          position: 'bottom',
          ticks: {
            autoSkip: false,
            callback: function(value, index) {
              if (index === 364 || index === 729 || index === 1094)
                return this.getLabelForValue(value);
              else
                return '';
            },
          }
        },
        y: {
          title: {
            display: false,
            text: 'Reward',
            font: {
              size: 16,
              weight: 'bold'
            }
          },
          ticks: {
            stepSize: 300,
            callback: function(value) {
              if (value == 0)
                return '$' + 100;
              else
                return '$' + value;
            }
          }
        }
      },
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
        tooltip: {
          callbacks: {
            label: function(context) {
              let label = context.dataset.label || '';

              if (label) {
                label += ': ';
              }
              if (context.parsed.y !== null) {
                label += new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                  style: 'currency',
                  currency: 'USD'
                }).format(context.parsed.y);
              }
              return label;
            }
          }
        }
      },
      animation: {
        duration: 1000, // Animation duration in milliseconds
        easing: 'easeInOutElastic' // Easing function for the animation
      },
      elements: {
        point: {
          radius: customRadius,
          display: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

function customRadius(context) {
  let index = context.dataIndex;
  let value = context.dataset.data[index];
  return index = 364 || index == 729 || index == 1094 ? 10 : 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="rewardOverTimeChart"></canvas>
```